# C# Retrieve selected item as an Object from Drop Down List of Objects

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm trying to retrieve the selected Object from a drop down list of Objects.

My current code is this:

```
// Drop Down List.
ddlTask.DataSource = access.GetTasks(); // List of Tasks

Task task = ddlTask.??? // ((GET SELECTED VALUE AS AN OBJECT))
```

Implementation for `GetTasks()` is:

```
public IList<Task> GetTasks()
{
    string qryString = "SELECT tk from Task tk";
    IQuery qryFindTasks = _session.CreateQuery(qryString);
    return qryFindTasks.List<Task>();
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Try `Task task = ddlTask.SelectedItem as Task`

Comment: @lokusking Says I cannot convert type IListItem into a Task

Comment: What does `GetTasks()` return, if it is already a list, you don't need `List<Task>`

Comment: @Legends, that's true, I've changed it but the error still persists.

Comment: Show the getTasks implementation..

Comment: @Legends - updated^

Comment: Is it a WinForm/WPF/WebForm application?

Comment: @Legends Straight after the datasource

Comment: @qxg it is a ASP page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `ddl.SelectedItem` is `ListItem`, you cannot get the object out of it, you have to use `ddl.SelectedItem.Text`  and `ddl.SelectedItem.Value` to get the Text and the Value of the selected item.

Then you can either create an object based on these values(for example):

```
var task = new Task(text,value);
```

or you have to query the store where you have loaded the Tasks from (for example):

```
 var selectedTask =  _session.GetTaskBySelectedValue(ddl.SelectedItem.Value);
```

to load the Task object again.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much how I got around this.

Answer (score 1):

If your ddlTask is a ComboBox then the datasource should be a collection and not a list of task and you should imply the displaymember of the comboboc to the selected collection column name.

ddlTask.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";

And then use the ddlTask.SelectedItem
or ddlTask.Text

Answer (score 0):

For other peeps trying to get an easy answer to this... consider in-place management and retrieval ...

```
Task selectedItem = null;
if(ddlTask.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        selectedItem = (Task)((IList<Task>)ddlTask.DataSource)[ddlTask.SelectedIndex];
```